# Xcode Source Trees usage in Bots

Tags: xcode6, xcode-bots

My project uses source trees to find it's dependent projects on disk.
But when running my bot, it cant find the dependent projects.

Do/can Bots use source trees or do I need to change the way we build products?

Comment: what do you mean by dependent projects?  Third party libraries or frameworks?  That would need to be managed by a source like cocoapods or carthage if you aren't embedding them into Xcode.

Comment: We have project on paths specified by source trees. When building via Bots, these projects cannot be found. So my question is doe Bots support source trees. If they do, my problem lies elsewhere

Comment: ah, i see now, the Xcode Source Trees.  while bots are created on your local machine, they do the work off of a server, so unless the source trees are also setup the same way on the server in the user that Xcode bot uses, it probably won't find them.  (Assuming that the source tree paths are relative to that machine)  You should be able to build a bot, run it, and then if it hangs or fails, look at the log and see where it got hung up

Comment: Well, the project builds fine in xcode but fails when running in a bot on the same machine. I'll see if I can fix it by creating the source paths manually by setting environment variables.